# Macro to conditionally generate tikz-cd diagrams

Tags: macros, tikz-cd, xstring, renewcommand, expandafter

I'm trying to define a macro that will generate a tikz-cd diagram with small changes in it based on the arguments I pass to the macro call. I'm using `xstring` package to express conditions.

My first attempt worked fine:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\myPic[1]{
\begin{tikzcd}[
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    execute at end picture={
      \IfStrEq{#1}{yes}{
        \draw (a) -- (b);
      }{
        \draw (a) -- (c);
      }
    }
  ]
  |[alias=a]| A \& |[alias=b]| B \\
  |[alias=c]| C \& D \\
\end{tikzcd}
}

\begin{document}

\myPic{yes}
\myPic{no}

\end{document}
```

But when I tried more sophisticated conditions and defined my macro as

```latex
\newcommand\myPic[1]{
\begin{tikzcd}[
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    execute at end picture={
      \IfStrEq{#1}{yes}{
        \draw (a) -- (b);
      }{
        \draw (a) -- (c);
      }
    }
  ]
  \IfStrEq{#1}{yes}{
    |[alias=a]| A \& |[alias=b]| B \\
  }{
    |[alias=a]| A \& B \\
    |[alias=c]| C \& D \\
  }
\end{tikzcd}
}
```

I started getting

```
main.tex:29:1: error: Package pgf Error: No shape named `a' is known.
```

errors. Can anyone please help me figure out why I'm getting them? I'm guessing that it's not evaluating my code in the order I expect, but I don't know how to fix or debug that.

And is there generally a way to achieve what I want?

Ivan

[image]

Comment: How does your output look like? My guess is it's not correctly creating the nodes because `\IfStrEq` is not fully expandable and the first `|[]|` is not correctly recognized. How many different kind of input parameters will you have besides `yes` and `no`? There are a few ways to solve this depending on how different your output will vary.

Comment: The example that compiles looks exactly like stackexchange has rendered it here, i.e. A connects to B when "yes" and to C when "no".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using an expandable string-equal test instead of the one provided by `xstring` your code works. The following creates a copy of the `expl3`-function `\str_if_eq:nnTF` for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \myifstreq \str_if_eq:nnTF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\myPic[1]{%
\begin{tikzcd}[
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    execute at end picture={%
      \myifstreq{#1}{yes}{%
        \draw (a) -- (b);
      }{%
        \draw (a) -- (c);
      }%
    }%
  ]
  \myifstreq{#1}{yes}{%
    |[alias=a]| A \& |[alias=b]| B \\
  }{%
    |[alias=a]| A \& B \\
    |[alias=c]| C \& D \\
  }%
\end{tikzcd}%
}

\begin{document}

\myPic{yes}
\myPic{no}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you intend to add even more different outputs, you might use `\str_case:nn` instead:

```
\documentclass[border=3.14]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \mystrcase \str_case:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\myPic[1]{%
\begin{tikzcd}[
    ampersand replacement=\&,
    execute at end picture={%
      \mystrcase{#1}
        {%
          {yes}{\draw (a) -- (b);}
          {no} {\draw (a) -- (c);}
        }%
    }%
  ]
  \mystrcase{#1}
    {%
      {yes}{|[alias=a]| A \& |[alias=b]| B \\}
      {no} {%
        |[alias=a]| A \& B \\
        |[alias=c]| C \& D \\
      }
    }%
\end{tikzcd}%
}

\begin{document}

\myPic{yes}
\myPic{no}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively you could create different macros storing the code for one of the different versions. This can be achieved with the following (for instance, other means are also possible):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mydrawing@yes{|[alias=a]| A \& |[alias=b]| B \\}
\newcommand\mydrawing@no
  {%
    |[alias=a]| A \& B \\
    |[alias=c]| C \& D \\
  }
\newcommand\myPic[1]{%
\begin{tikzcd}
  \ifcsname mydrawing@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
    \csname mydrawing@\detokenize{#1}\endcsname
  \else
    \ERROR
  \fi
\end{tikzcd}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a great answer — very useful!